# SelectBoxIt - trigger an update to the original select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, selectboxit

I'm trying to use the [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) jQuery plugin and it looks great and promising and everything though i have 1 issue with this plugin, it seems that there is no native way to update the original select element with the selected value.

at first look on the documentations it seems that indeed there is an option to do so:

> Aggressive Change Mode
>
> Note: Aggressive Change Mode will select a drop down option (and
> trigger the change event on the original select box) when a user
> navigates to an option using the up and down arrow keys via the
> keyboard, or searches for an option using the keyboard.

the words:

> trigger the change event on the original select box

confused me for a moment but as you can see this is not my use case, it is only referring for a navigation with the keyboard and updating the new drop-down created by the plugin.

am i missing something or there is no native way of doing what i ask for?
and if so, what would be consider a best practice for updating the **original** select element?
i already thought of some options using callbacks or change events but not sure what would be consider as best practice.

Comment: Can you add the snippet

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue? I am having it now.